# Kartik's star-rating widget not working in foreach construction in Yii2

Tags: yii2

- Image with problem form site:

[image]

- Link for widget: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-rating.

**QUESTION:**
Why instead of stars, appear loading symbols (stars are not displayed), for all elements, except first

**CODE:**

```
foreach($posts as $post):
    <span class="star-container">  

        debug($post->post_rate);
        echo StarRating::widget([
            'model' => $post,
            'attribute' => 'post_rate',
            'pluginOptions' => [
                    'size'=>'xs',
                    'filledStar' => '&#x2605;',
                    'emptyStar' => '&#x2606;',
                ]
        ]);
    </span>
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add ids or names to your widgets.

```
echo StarRating::widget([
            'model' => $post,
            'id' => $post->id
            'attribute' => 'post_rate',
            'pluginOptions' => [
                    'size'=>'xs',
                    'filledStar' => '&#x2605;',
                    'emptyStar' => '&#x2606;',
                ]
        ]);
```